# PreparedStatement IF EXISTS throws: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, postgresql-9.6

Following code throws exception:

```
String sql = "DO $$ " +
            "BEGIN " +
            "IF EXISTS ( SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='myTable' AND column_name='myColumn') THEN " +
            "UPDATE myTable SET \"myColumn\"=? WHERE \"id\"=1; " +
            "END IF; " +
            "END " +
            "$$; ";

Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql)
pstmt.setString(1, "bla bla"); // <--- EXCEPTION HERE
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

If I'm changing sql to this then it's fine:

```
String sql = "UPDATE myTable SET \"myColumn\"=? WHERE \"id\"=1;";
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to update some columns only if they exists...

Comment: Do you have select access for information_schema.COLUMNS?

Comment: Why don't you just run the  `UPDATE` without the PL/pgSQL block and catch any exception that results from that? Or run the `if exists` in a separate JDBC call and do the `if` inside Java?

Comment: @MichaelPeacock yes I do

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to update 50000 so performance will be really bad

Comment: Why would you need to check 50000 columns if they exist? That sounds like a terrible design

Comment: I'm running 50000 updates queries for different rows (not columns)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres docs says:

> PREPARE name [ ( data_type [, ...] ) ] AS statement
>
> ...
>
> statement
>
> ```
> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement.
> ```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-prepare.html

So it seems you can't prepare anonymous code block and I guess your code:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql)
```

does not prepare anything. You can check it by making sql request:

```
select * from pg_prepared_statements;
```

If you change your code like this:

```
String sql = "DO $$ whatever $$;";

Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
((org.postgresql.PGStatement)pstmt).setPrepareThreshold(1); // <-- Add this line
// pstmt.setString(1, "bla bla"); // comment it out
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

you get the actual postgres error about wrong statement to prepare.

Comment: I can't comment `pstmt.setString` because my query contains `'?'` parameter